# getting null pointer using pageradapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I implement tabs using action bar and viewpager in my app. I want to have access to the fragment of one of the tabs in the host activity. here is my pagerAdapter code:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Fragment screens[];
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MainActivity2 context) {
        super(fm);
        screens = new Fragment[4];
        screens[3] = Fragment.instantiate(context,CoachFragment.class.getName() );
        screens[2] = Fragment.instantiate(context,LogingFragment.class.getName() );
        screens[1] = Fragment.instantiate(context,ToolbarFragment.class.getName() );
        screens[0] = Fragment.instantiate(context,HistoryFragment.class.getName() );
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        if(index <= screens.length)
        {
            return screens[index];
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return screens.length;
    }
}
```

in my code after all setups I have line below:

```
CoachFragment fragment = (CoachFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(3);
    fragment.setProgress(dor);
```

my fragment is not null but in setProgress() in CoachFragment I got nullpointer in one of the objects. but I instantiate that object in oncreatview() of CoachFragmwnt. How this is possible when a fragment object is not null but onCreateView() is not called?

Comment: It depends when you call that code. You've created a fragment but that fragment will not be fully initialized until a transaction attaches it to the activity.

Comment: yeah you are right. my mistake was that I should set actionbar tab once to items 3 to create its fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How this is possible when a fragment object is not null but onCreateView() is not called?

Yes, it happened.
`Fragment.instantiate` just create an Object, but not call it's callback methods like `onCreateView()`

The callback methods will be called in the adapter later.

I think you can move the `fragment.setProgress(dor);` to:

1. the `onResume()` of the Activity.
2. the Fragment's callback method, like `onCreateView()`.